# Where can I find a description of vim's verbose levels/settings?

Tags: vim, verbose

I've been searching through vim's help, but haven't been able to find a list of all the verbose levels and what is output by each level.

After playing around and reading the docs, I've found:

- 0 - when vim is not started with `-V`, verbose is set to 0.
- 6 - displays removal of buffer-local autocommands
- 9 - echo autocommands as vim executes them
- 10 - default level when started with `vim -V` and level is not specified, displays names of files as they are sourced
- 13 - displays exceptions?
- 20 - max level?

Answer (score 4):

From `:help 'verbose'` :

```
'verbose' 'vbs'     number  (default 0)
            global
            {not in Vi, although some versions have a boolean
            verbose option}
    When bigger than zero, Vim will give messages about what it is doing.
    Currently, these messages are given:
    >= 1    When the viminfo file is read or written.
    >= 2    When a file is ":source"'ed.
    >= 5    Every searched tags file and include file.
    >= 8    Files for which a group of autocommands is executed.
    >= 9    Every executed autocommand.
    >= 12   Every executed function.
    >= 13   When an exception is thrown, caught, finished, or discarded.
    >= 14   Anything pending in a ":finally" clause.
    >= 15   Every executed Ex command (truncated at 200 characters).

    This option can also be set with the "-V" argument.  See |-V|.
    This option is also set by the |:verbose| command.
```

Comment: Ah - `:h verbose` is not the same as `:h 'verbose'`, thank you. :) Strange that `:helpgrep verbose` didn't find that page.

Comment: @nfarrar : `:help` pages in quotes are help pages about options (just as `:h v_d` would show the help about `d` in visual mode). See `:help help-context` for a full list.

Answer (score 2):

**verbosity level**

```
vim -V20/tmp/log filename

save verbose 20 to filename /tmp/log

When bigger than zero, Vim will give messages about what it is doing. Currently, these messages are given: 
>= 1 When the viminfo file is read or written. 
>= 2 When a file is ":source"'ed. 
>= 5 Every searched tags file and include file. 
>= 8 Files for which a group of autocommands is executed. 
>= 9 Every executed autocommand. 
>= 12 Every executed function. 
>= 13 When an exception is thrown, caught, finished, or discarded. 
>= 14 Anything pending in a ":finally" clause. 
>= 15 Every executed Ex command (truncated at 200 characters).
```

This is a short snapshot from [this link](http://vimberlin.de/data/vimberlin-2013-09_vimprofiling)